# Match in Python

Tags: python, excel, compare, match

I have two excel files. Two files also have about 200 000 lines. (I give just six lines in examples.)

file1.xlsx

```
  M1          M2          M3        M4
97.1859   -59.1873     0.000912    4.55
63.116    -75.958      0.003797    20.85
112.09    -22.9276     0.005008    2.26
320.7931  -63.4153     0.008382    7.45
337.8978  -72.8617     0.009965    3.88
99.2183   -56.5418     0.018141    18.17
```

file2.xlsx

```
 N1        N2      N3     N4       N5          N6
0.057      4       Im    6.61    0.005008    38.85929
0.065      36      Im    9.27    0.003797   -19.4988
0.062      68      Im    8.06    0.008382   -51.8935
0.066      46      Im    8.55    0.009965   -40.5912
                   Im    9.1     0.000912     1.089013
0.075      32      Im    12.31   0.018141     3.946489
```

M3(in file1) and N5(in file2) columns the same.

According to M3-N5 columns, I want to match these two files and create third file(output file) in Python.

output.xlsx

```
   M1        M2          M3-N5       M4    N1     N2   N3    N4          N5
97.1859   -59.1873     0.000912    4.55                Im    9.1       1.089013
63.116    -75.958      0.003797    20.85  0.065   36   Im    9.27    -19.4988
112.09    -22.9276     0.005008    2.26   0.057    4   Im    6.61     38.85929
320.7931  -63.4153     0.008382    7.45   0.062   68   Im    8.06    -51.8935
337.8978  -72.8617     0.009965    3.88   0.066   46   Im    8.55    -40.5912
99.2183   -56.5418     0.018141    18.17  0.075   32   Im    12.31     3.946489
```

I did in a program called TOPCAT but I want to do in Python for comparison. However I've started to use new Python so I can not write detailed codes.

How can I do this? Which code can I get it through?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for providing input and output data. It makes your question very clear. To help you we also ideally need to see what you have tried and where exactly you are stuck. However my advice is not to use Python at all but to simply import this into a database (e.g. sqlite, mysql, postgresql) and get your output with a query joining the two tables. I don't know what happens if you try and join on floats though - there may be a simple way round that if you look.

Comment: If you must do this in Python you should look at the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library.

Answer (score 3):

Use pandas.

read de files:

```
dfi = pandas.read_excel('myexcel_i')
```

make the common column (the one used as the joining reference) the dataframe index:

```
dfi = dfi.set_index(my_column)
```

join the two excels

```
df = pandas.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

save to a new file:

```
df.to_excel('myfile.xlsx')
```

Comment: @SaulloCastro they are merged by index. You do not need to alineate them.

Comment: @SaulloCastro bit a bit our answers are converging ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Using [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) you can do this task like:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_excel('file1.xlsx', 'Sheet1')
df1.sort(columns='M3')

df2 = pd.read_excel('file2.xlsx', 'Sheet1')
df2.sort(columns='N5')

df3 = pd.concat((df1, df2), axis=1)

df3 = df3.sort(axis=1)

df3.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

NOTE: the sorting operations above are not required if you use `set_index` as explained in @joaquin's answer...

Comment: ExcelFile + parse have been deprecated in pandas. Use read_excel

Comment: Also you have to set the dataframes indexes as columns M3 and N5, respectively, otherwise, it wouldnt work. see my answer.

Comment: Column name 'M3-N5' doesnt mean a substration, just the name hyphenated. You do not need to create this column as it will be the first column in the excel file (the index) nor delete 'M3'.

Comment: You are right! I've updated the answer and also adding the fact that they must be sorted before concatenated... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with excel files in python, you generally have two approaches:

- Use win32com. This is an API for controlling windows programs such as Excel, Word, Outlook etc.

The basic process is simple to understand, and looks like this:

```
import win32com.client
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
```

From there you can use excel native commands such as:

```
excel.Visible = True #show the excel
excel.Workbooks.Add() #open a workbook
print excel.Cells(1, 1).Value #print the value of a cell at position 1, 1
```

This is especially good when you need to use some excel related functionalities (because     it's just a system to control excel through python). However, you might better like...

- using xlrd and xlwt (which stand for excel-read and excel-write, accordingly). Using those libraries you can read and write unto excel with easier pythonic-styled languages, and also you can access any excel-type file (including the OpenOffice 'excel' sheets and the like).

You should definitly check out the [documentation for both libraries](http://www.python-excel.org), but here's a simple example:

```
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('my_workbook.xls')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
```

Also, check out the [examples here](http://www.youlikeprogramming.com/2012/03/examples-reading-excel-xls-documents-using-pythons-xlrd/), and google around a bit to learn how to use those.

--

When you finally decide on the approach you want to take, do your best to solve it, and if you have trouble with the code or it isn't working like you excepted, come back here to SO, show us your code, and someone will definitly help you out. Good luck!